# AWS ACM - One or more domain names have failed validation due to a Certificate Authority Authentication (CAA) error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, dns, windows-server-2019, aws-certificate-manager

I am using Window Server 2019 for DNS management.

I have created a public SSL certificate for domain `*.example.mydomain.hk` in AWS Certificate Manager(ACM)

After that, I add The DNS configuration for the SSL cert.

Below image is get from online.
My setting:

```
Alias name: _66fxxxxxxxxx(auto generated after entering Full qualified domain name)
Full qualified domain name: _66fxxxxxxxxx.example.mydomain.hk
Fully qualified domain name for target host: _3ddxxxxxxxx.abcde.acm-validations.aws.
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
But error occur in ACM and the status become failed

> The status of this certificate request is "Failed". One or more domain names have failed validation due to a Certificate Authority Authentication (CAA) error.

```
When I `dig _66fxxxxxxxxx.example.mydomain.hk`, it shows:
```

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> _66fxxxxxxxxx.example.mydomain.hk.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12345
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_66fxxxxxxxxx.example.mydomain.hk. IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_66fxxxxxxxxx.example.mydomain.hk. 3599 IN CNAME _3ddxxxxxxxx.abcde.acm-validations.aws.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
abcde.acm-validations.aws.  899 IN  SOA ns-75.awsdns-09.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

...

```
How should I solve this issue?

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohEdu.png
```

Comment: There are [CAA records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_Certification_Authority_Authorization) in the DNS which define a policy about which CA is allowed to issue certificates within this specific domain. The one you use is not allowed to do this and therefore it fails.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich How can I find it?

Comment: See the linked reference to Wikipedia which also contains information on how these CAA records look like. Use the DNS lookup tool of your choice - which need to be able to look up arbitrary records though (or at least CAA), i.e. `dig CAA mydomain.hk`

Comment: Also your CA should be able to help you and diagnose the issue, did you ask them? Besides, your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally added a CAA Record for `*.example.mydomain.hk` and works now.

```
*.example.mydomain.hk  IN  CAA 0 issue "amazon.com"
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I have requested both
example.com and *.example.com certificates through ACM.

I had to setup the following to make it work.

```
CAA example.com 0 issue amazon.com
CAA example.com 0 issuewild amazon.com
```

DO NOT USE *.example.com to setup CAA for the wildcard domain, you just need to add the main domain and issuewild tag.

Comment: I can confirm that this is working

Comment: Just switched to this approach  any idea how long AWS takes to attempt a renewal?

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar issue when migrating my nextjs app from vercel to AWS amplify.

In this case, vercel CNAME records add CAA records from their en

[image]

- I deleted vercel's CNAME record and this issue got resolved
- I didn't need a CAA record for amazon.com

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was running into the same issue for one of my domains when I would attempt to create ACM cert and validate through DNS.

I needed to add a CAA record in route53 and set the value to `0 issue "amazon.com"` and this allowed  DNS validation for the ACM cert to pass for my record in R53

Answer (score 0):

for those who use cloudflare, and have some trouble issueing Amazon Certificate Manager, you can go to cloudflare dashboard, and Add record:

Type: CAA
Name: @ (or use your requsted domain name)
Tag: Only allow spesific hostname
CA Domain Name: amazon.com
TTL: Auto